# Separação do Banco do Identity com o da Aplicação

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, ddd

Ao utilizar o Asp.net Identity é gerado um banco só para ele.
E é recomendado deixar esse banco só para o Identity e criar um outro banco para a sua aplicação, como li em alguns artigos.

Até ai tudo bem... Dai fui ver uma vídeo-aula (link na última linha) do Eduardo Pires onde ele cria uma entidade Usuario no domínio da aplicação com os mesmos dados da tabela "AspNetUsers", e no repositório ele aponta para o banco do Identity e mapeia a entidade Usuario para a tabela "AspNetUsers" e, com isso, posso
mexer na tabela Usuario do Identity como se fosse no banco do meu sistema.

E minha dúvida surge a partir dai:

Na minha aplicação também devo ter um Usuario, porém com dados relacionados ao negócio (CPF, Cidade, Lista de Produtos, OutraEntidade, etc), além dos dados já contidos na tabela AspNetUsers.
Mas não posso apontar esse Usuario para o banco do Identity, pois dai já estaria misturando tabelas do banco da aplicação com o banco do Identity. Entretanto preciso da tabela do Identity para fazer o controle do Usuario. Como posso fazer essa separação?

Link da vídeo-aula:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GGPANv47Z3k (a partir do minuto 30:20)

Projeto no Github:
https://github.com/EduardoPires/IdentityIsolation/tree/master/src

Comment: Por que "*[...] é recomendado deixar esse banco só para o Identity e criar um outro banco para a sua aplicação*"?

Comment: Concordo com o ponto do @jbueno. Qual seria a razão? Banco é banco. Uso das entidades dependerá exclusivamente do seu modelo.

Comment: Essa recomendação de separação não faz o menor sentido, tanto que [existe este pacote que integra o Identity com o Entity Framework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/). Essa vídeo-aula é uma coleção de más práticas.

Comment: Então posso acrescentar dados, relacionamentos no AspNetUsers e nas outras tabelas do Identity sem problema nenhum? Porque achei estranho ter dois bancos para um unica aplicação.

Comment: Não precisa ser dois bancos, você pode colocar tudo em um banco de dados só, eu acho que fica até mais fácil de trabalhar assim.

Comment: Pois é Ricardo, também acho, mas como sou iniciante ainda então fiquei meio confuso. Irei trabalhar com um banco mesmo.

Comment: Eu uso o identity no meu banco externo sem problema algum....e detalhe, customizado. O legal da versão 2.x é justamente por ter mais flexibilidade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apenas sob ponto de vista da orientação ao objeto, evite usar herança nesse caso, use agregação. O que você está chamando de `Usuario` no seu modelo de negócios não é um usuário, é uma `Pessoa` (ou outro nome que preferir utilizar), a qual possui um usuário que lhe permite acessar o sistema com algum papel. Pois essa pessoa tem CPF e dados que em princípio não pertencem a uma classe `Usuario`. Este sim, possui dados relacionados a identidade e autorização, tais como "login", "senha", "papeis", etc.

Uma entidade que represente uma pessoa dentro do seu sistema (que poderia ser até mesmo uma pessoa jurídica com CNPJ) deve apenas "referenciar" um Usuario das tabelas de AspNetIdentity. Essa referência pode (ou deve) ser fraca, guardando apenas o Id do usuário, por exemplo, caso você deseje manter os bancos separados (não seria possível manter integridade referencial mesmo).

Levando mais adiante, o mesmo usuário pode ser "utilizado" por mais de uma pessoa. Em vários sistemas que escrevo existem usuários que permitem o acesso a diferentes pessoas simultaneamente (o usuário escolhe qual "pessoa" irá usar após o logon). Isso permite um contador, por exemplo, logar em diversos clientes dele, sem precisar lembrar senhas e logins diferentes para cada um. Mas só adicione essa complexidade se o seu modelo de negócios exigir.

A sugestão de se manter separado o banco de dados de usuários é porque você pode vir a ter usuários que se conectem de outros provedores de identidade, como Google e Facebook. Tentar manter uma separação quase total entre o controle de "acesso" ao seu sistema e o sistema em si é muito interessante. Além disso, permite que outros sistemas possam usar o mesmo banco de dados de usuário, sem, necessariamente utilizar o mesmo banco de dados do sistema em si.

Minha sugestão é que coloque o banco de dados com a tabela AspNetUsers no mesmo banco da sua aplicação, pois isso simplifica as coisas, principalmente para iniciantes, mas evitaria a todo custo criar dependências entre as tabelas/objetos de negócio e as tabelas de usuários. Como disse, guarde o ID do usuário quando precisar dessa referência, sem criar uma *Foreign Key* (referência de integridade) entre as tabelas.